# How to return complete object graph using WCF Data Services?

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

I have a class model that is recursive in nature. For brevity, I'll describe it as:

- A **Template** contains many **Socket** objects
- A **Socket** accepts many **Template** objects

I typically end up with object graphs that look like this:

```
  Root Template
     |--> Sockets
             |--> Socket S1
             |       |--> Templates
             |               |--> Template T1
             |               |--> Template T2
             |                       |--> Sockets
             |                               |--> Socket S1.1
             |--> Socket S2
                     |--> Templates
                             |--> Template T2  <-- it's valid to reuse templates
                             |--> Template T3
                             etc
```

**I want to return the entire object graph via WCF Data Services in one shot.**

I've added a custom method to my DataService that builds the full graph:

```
    [WebGet]
    public IEnumerable<Template> GetFullyExpandedTemplate(Guid templateId)
    {
        var result = _templateRepo.GetFullyExpandedTemplate(a => a.Id == templateId);
        return new List<Template>() { result };
    }
```

The result is definitely fully populated (verified . But if I browse to the following:

```
http://localhost/MySite/MyDataService.svc/GetFullyExpandedAggregate?id=guid'353934DD-916E-43EC-9CAE-EAB8FA894EBA'
```

I only see the *Root Template* object - it doesn't bring back the *entire graph*.

Any ideas on the *cleanest* way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Would the $expand url option work for you?  You might have to switch to querying on an entity set instead of a custom method though.

Comment: Because it's recursive, the client has no idea how deep the object graph could go.  In the context of this particular application, returning the object graph in one go seems the most effective method.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done AFAIK. At best, you could intercept requests against the service op and redirect to a URI w/ the full expansion, but the expand paths would still be static.